# mysql query to compare previous , current and next value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have mysql table called 'peak_data' . iam new to mysql and php.

here is the definition of the peak

i already converted time data into unix time by using **strtotime()** . So using this value we can uniquely identify each and every row.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Are you looking for SQL or math?

Comment: can comparison part doing bu using mysql? this is not homework quection. getting idea from newspaper.

Comment: Ahh, then this goes way beyond my knowledge of SQL and MySQL, so go with the answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is to get the next and previous values of "y" (or whatever the value column is called).  You can do this in SQL-only using correlated subqueries.

Once you have these values, you can then count the number of peaks and the maximum peak using aggregation:

```
select sum(nexty < y and prevy < y) as NumPeaks,
       max(case when nexty < y and prevy < y then y end) as MaxPeak
from (select pd.*,
             (select y
              from peak_data pd1
              where pd1.time < pd.time
              order by pd1.time desc
              limit 1
             ) prevy,
             (select y
              from peak_data pd1
              where pd1.time > pd.time
              order by pd1.time asc
              limit 1
             ) nexty
      from peak_data pd
     ) pd;
```

Note that the maximum peak value is not necessarily the maximum value of "y", because the most recent or first value in the table could be the maximum.  They do not, however, count as peaks by your definition.